# Undefined error when attempting to use the openai api

Tags: javascript, node.js, openai-api

Been trying to use the openai api. After realizing I was using syntax for the legacy api I switched it for the 3.5 version. Now appear to be getting an undefined error. Not sure, but I might be doing something wrong syntax-wise again? Any ideas on the issue?

Error:

```
PS C:\Demo> node index.js
undefined
```

Code:

```
import { Configuration, OpenAIApi } from "openai";

const configuration = new Configuration({
    organization: "Placeholder",
    apiKey: "Placeholder" 
});
  
const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

const completion = await openai.createChatCompletion({  // Functions must be /v1/chat/completions compatible: 
  model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",  
  messages: [
    {role: "user", content: "How are you today?"},
  ]
});
console.log(completion.data.choices[0].text); // print text response from response object
```

UPDATE ADDED Completion Object:

```
{
  status: 200,
  statusText: 'OK',
  headers: {
    date: 'Sat, 29 Jul 2023 04:47:38 GMT',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'content-length': '492',
    connection: 'close',
    'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache, must-revalidate',
    'openai-model': 'gpt-3.5-turbo-0613',
    'openai-organization': 'user-kkvsk8yyp8b4vxwiot1omana',
    'openai-processing-ms': '1666',
    'openai-version': '2020-10-01',
    'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains',
    'x-ratelimit-limit-requests': '200',
    'x-ratelimit-limit-tokens': '40000',
    'x-ratelimit-remaining-requests': '197',
    'x-ratelimit-remaining-tokens': '39978',
    'x-ratelimit-reset-requests': '15m0.985s',
    'x-ratelimit-reset-tokens': '33ms',
    'x-request-id': '97ffedd744caa7b206f878d2200c90a5',
    'cf-cache-status': 'DYNAMIC',
    server: 'cloudflare',
    'cf-ray': '7ee2b98bc8b0d9d1-MIA',
    'alt-svc': 'h3=":443"; ma=86400'
  },
  config: {
    transitional: {
      silentJSONParsing: true,
      forcedJSONParsing: true,
      clarifyTimeoutError: false
    },
    adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
    transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
    transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
    timeout: 0,
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    maxBodyLength: -1,
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'User-Agent': 'OpenAI/NodeJS/3.3.0',
      Authorization: 'Bearer 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',
      'OpenAI-Organization': 'org-UfIKVGWEJyAhjwRVK9wrMBRZ',
      'Content-Length': 85
    },
    method: 'post',
    data: '{"model":"gpt-3.5-turbo","messages":[{"role":"user","content":"How are you today?"}]}',
    url: 'https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions'
  },
  request: <ref *1> ClientRequest {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      abort: [Function (anonymous)],
      aborted: [Function (anonymous)],
      connect: [Function (anonymous)],
      error: [Function (anonymous)],
      socket: [Function (anonymous)],
      timeout: [Function (anonymous)],
      finish: [Function: requestOnFinish]
    },
    _eventsCount: 7,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    outputData: [],
    outputSize: 0,
    writable: true,
    destroyed: false,
    _last: true,
    chunkedEncoding: false,
    shouldKeepAlive: false,
    maxRequestsOnConnectionReached: false,
    _defaultKeepAlive: true,
    useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
    sendDate: false,
    _removedConnection: false,
    _removedContLen: false,
    _removedTE: false,
    strictContentLength: false,
    _contentLength: 85,
    _hasBody: true,
    _trailer: '',
    finished: true,
    _headerSent: true,
    _closed: false,
    socket: TLSSocket {
      _tlsOptions: [Object],
      _secureEstablished: true,
      _securePending: false,
      _newSessionPending: false,
      _controlReleased: true,
      secureConnecting: false,
      _SNICallback: null,
      servername: 'api.openai.com',
      alpnProtocol: false,
      authorized: true,
      authorizationError: null,
      encrypted: true,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 10,
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: 'api.openai.com',
      _closeAfterHandlingError: false,
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: false,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: undefined,
      _server: null,
      ssl: [TLSWrap],
      _requestCert: true,
      _rejectUnauthorized: true,
      parser: null,
      _httpMessage: [Circular *1],
      [Symbol(res)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(verified)]: true,
      [Symbol(pendingSession)]: null,
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 10,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
      [Symbol(kSetKeepAlive)]: true,
      [Symbol(kSetKeepAliveInitialDelay)]: 60,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(connect-options)]: [Object]
    },
    _header: 'POST /v1/chat/completions HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
      'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
      'Content-Type: application/json\r\n' +
      'User-Agent: OpenAI/NodeJS/3.3.0\r\n' +
      'Authorization: Bearer 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\r\n' +
      'OpenAI-Organization: org-UfIKVGWEJyAhjwRVK9wrMBRZ\r\n' +
      'Content-Length: 85\r\n' +
      'Host: api.openai.com\r\n' +
      'Connection: close\r\n' +
      '\r\n',
    _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
    _onPendingData: [Function: nop],
    agent: Agent {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      defaultPort: 443,
      protocol: 'https:',
      options: [Object: null prototype],
      requests: [Object: null prototype] {},
      sockets: [Object: null prototype],
      freeSockets: [Object: null prototype] {},
      keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
      keepAlive: false,
      maxSockets: Infinity,
      maxFreeSockets: 256,
      scheduling: 'lifo',
      maxTotalSockets: Infinity,
      totalSocketCount: 1,
      maxCachedSessions: 100,
      _sessionCache: [Object],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    socketPath: undefined,
    method: 'POST',
    maxHeaderSize: undefined,
    insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
    joinDuplicateHeaders: undefined,
    path: '/v1/chat/completions',
    _ended: true,
    res: IncomingMessage {
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 4,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      socket: [TLSSocket],
      httpVersionMajor: 1,
      httpVersionMinor: 1,
      httpVersion: '1.1',
      complete: true,
      rawHeaders: [Array],
      rawTrailers: [],
      joinDuplicateHeaders: undefined,
      aborted: false,
      upgrade: false,
      url: '',
      method: null,
      statusCode: 200,
      statusMessage: 'OK',
      client: [TLSSocket],
      _consuming: false,
      _dumped: false,
      req: [Circular *1],
      responseUrl: 'https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions',
      redirects: [],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kHeaders)]: [Object],
      [Symbol(kHeadersCount)]: 44,
      [Symbol(kTrailers)]: null,
      [Symbol(kTrailersCount)]: 0
    },
    aborted: false,
    timeoutCb: null,
    upgradeOrConnect: false,
    parser: null,
    maxHeadersCount: null,
    reusedSocket: false,
    host: 'api.openai.com',
    protocol: 'https:',
    _redirectable: Writable {
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 3,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _options: [Object],
      _ended: true,
      _ending: true,
      _redirectCount: 0,
      _redirects: [],
      _requestBodyLength: 85,
      _requestBodyBuffers: [],
      _onNativeResponse: [Function (anonymous)],
      _currentRequest: [Circular *1],
      _currentUrl: 'https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions',
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
    [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype] {
      accept: [Array],
      'content-type': [Array],
      'user-agent': [Array],
      authorization: [Array],
      'openai-organization': [Array],
      'content-length': [Array],
      host: [Array]
    },
    [Symbol(errored)]: null,
    [Symbol(kHighWaterMark)]: 16384,
    [Symbol(kRejectNonStandardBodyWrites)]: false,
    [Symbol(kUniqueHeaders)]: null
  },
  data: {
    id: 'chatcmpl-7hW9YTnN96BXLqCsurIMqzCpdD9EJ',
    object: 'chat.completion',
    created: 1690606056,
    model: 'gpt-3.5-turbo-0613',
    choices: [ [Object] ],
    usage: { prompt_tokens: 12, completion_tokens: 27, total_tokens: 39 }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thats not 100% error, all we appear to know is that completion.data.choices[0].text is undefined.  It could be that its in a different field then text or there is more error information your missing.  Can you do more logging to see whats actually happening? Can you show the actual full completion object?

Comment: The full completion object is a bit long, so I neglected to include it. Adding to post currently. Looking at it closer I may be accessing the response incorrectly?

Comment: I had thought from the documentation choices[0] to access the object and then .text was the correct syntax to access the response. Honestly unsure.

Answer (score 0):

Truly was an issue with the syntax. Forgot to switch the legacy gpt syntax for:

```
completion.data.choices[0].text
```

to the gpt 3.5 version syntax of:

```
completion.data.choices[0].message
```